# Moderating Variable in R

Tags: r, regression, interaction, structural-equation-modeling

I've been looking for Moderating equations in R but to no avail. Can somebody tell me how to write the moderating equations in R ? assuming one perdictor, one dependent variable and one covariates. Do i have to install any packages ? sry i'm not that good with R . Thanks for the helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moderation is simply another word for "interaction" and the simplest way to do it is to add a variable that is the moderator multiplied by the other independent variable and also add the moderator to the regression equation.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the help . Appreciate it. So you are saying that we can just do it like the mediating variable

Comment: No. Mediation is a different thing.